# Node.js Twit Twitter Module

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, twitter

I'm having a little problem figuring out how to follow, like retweet someone's tweet.

[image]
As you can probably see I can get all tweet's mentioning justinbieber but i want to be able to put somecode in the function to either retweet or like the status or even follow the user that tweeted it.

If you managed to understand all of that jumble I'd appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What stream.on(...) does is call the function in the second parameter every time a tweet comes up, and it passes the tweet itself as a parameter. So every action you want to do with that tweet, you need to do it in the function.

To see all information on the tweet object you can go on the [Twitter API page](https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/tweets). You have access to all of this in your anonymous function !

For retweeting every tweet :

```
...
stream.on('tweet', function(tweet) {

    T.post('statuses/retweet/:id', { id: tweet.id_str }, function (err, data, response) {
        console.log(data)
    })

})
```

Syntax taken from [twit module documentation](https://github.com/ttezel/twit/blob/master/README.md)

First time answering, I hope this helps.